# Setting up 2 SSL Sites with 2 IP's and different certs in IIS 7

Tags: c#, ssl, iis, https, certificate

I have created an aditional IP in order to host 2 Sites and set up an HTTPS Binding for them.
I've set the binding where each uses 1 IP and both are set to 443 and their own certificate.

Once I've reseted the sites everything worked fine. Both open in https are there no certificate issues. The problem I'm facing is when those sites call a second server. Then I get errors like:

[Error Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLXM8.png)

This happenes for both Sites. I've checked the Host file the second server and both IP's are added there. Once I've changed 1 of the sites back from the specific IP to All Unassigned then that Site worked fine again. But the second site that still has the specific IP does not work in that regard. I can't have both set to all Unassigned and it's confusing me why setting it to that ,when it still uses that IP anyway ,makes it not work.

A while ago only 1 was https and the other http and then it all worked fine. Now that I've tried making both HTTPS I started having issues with contacting second server. Both of the servers support TLS1.2 , 1.1 and 1.0
At the begging I've disabled 1.1 but tried enabling it to see if thats the issue.
I've also tried some suggestions online like adding these lines before making a call to the server:

"System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };"

To test if it's the certificate issue and I've also tried setting TLS1.2 here and updated the project to use .net4.6

Any advices would be appreciated

EDIT:

I've created the test on the actual server and the error is the same:
[Test Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZkyWN.png)

For some reason I can't choose .Net4.6 even when I click on Install other frameworks the [Target Framework](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BfGdr.png) is always the same.

Comment: Do both server have the same version of Net Installed?  When an application is deployed on a machine the version of Net has to be the same as the build machine.  If they are not the same then you have to publish application and install using the setup.exe.  You may also have an issue with cookies.  There may be a cookie that need to get deleted because properties have changed.  The cookie on the server may be set so it is using http while the new code is using https.

Comment: Hi , Thanks for trying to help. Both servers have .NET 4.8.03761. I've used this in CMD "reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\full" /v version". You mean a cookie in the request to the server?

Comment: Microsoft often changes default settings when changing Net Versions so you may have issues with differences between Net 4.6 and Net 4.8.  Many people have had issues with upgrading to Net 4.7 and Net 4.8 due to changes in TLS/SSL which is used in HTTPS.  A cookie and a Expiration Time so old cookie may still be used with the new code which can crate issues.   Some Expiration times for cookies could be months.

Comment: I've checked the code but the Cookie is not used in this part of the code. I do however has a function that creates one:

Web request = base.GetWebRequest(address);
request.Timeout = 60*60*1000;
if(request is HttpWebRequest) {  (request as HttpWebRequest).CookieContainer = cookie; }
return request;

But this is not used for the call.

Regarding the .NET , should I try updating code to use 4.8?

Comment: Not sure due to a lot of people having issues with upgrading when using SSL/TLS.  Upgrading may break both connections.  The certificate should contains the key type.   When SSL/TLS is used in windows the code check the TLS/SSL mode and then choices the correct encryption mode.  Most c# application on are designed to handle one mode.  In c# you the encryption mode is an enumeration (1,2,4,8,16,32 as values) and you can OR the modes together.  But then when the response fails you have to send another request with a different mode.  The Net library request doesn't do the retires.

Comment: I've been messing around with Binding settings. And changing from the Private IP to All Unassigned makes this work. I'm no really sure what you mean by that and what I should try and do. But seems like these IP are not trusted?

Comment: You need to run from cmd.exe >IPConfig/All to see all the network IP and masks that are on the machine.  chang from Private IP to Public would just change the IP address range determined by the IP and mask.

Comment: I've checked that and I only have 2 private IP adresses with the same subnet mask.
Not sure what to do with this information?

Comment: IIS don't support Server name indication. So there would be some SSL corruption issue when you host mutiple https sites. Have you tried to use same certificate with mutiple SAN for both sites?

Comment: Both certificates have only 1 SAN and it's the same as Common Name. But I don't think the same certificate would work for both of them because of that common name. 1 of the certificates I downloaded my self but the other one I received by the owner of the domain.

If I were to remove https from 1 site. And enable only the other site with a specific IP designed for it , do you think that could test the SSL corruption?

Comment: I can't get a multiple SAN cert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem. The issue was with the Host file , but not the one from the server I'm trying to call , but the actual localhost. The domain was using local IP 127.0.0.1 the same as what my other domain was using since it's set to "All Unassinged". Then calling the server as the domain would actually return wrong cert and that would break it.

I just changed the IP for both domains from local IP to a specific Private IP and it worked.

Thanks for help jdweng and Jokies Ding!